# Get key from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I just started with Python,

Is there some iteration in dictionary like in PHP

```
foreach(aData as key=>value)
```

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like something like this :

```
my_dict = {"key1": 1, "key2":2}
my_dict.items()       # in python < 3 , you should use iteritems()
>>> ("key1", 1), ("key2", 2)
```

so you can iterate on it :

```
for key, value in my_dict.items():
   do_the_stuff(key, value)
```

Comment: In the same time I want to get one key and the data as well

Answer (score 5):

assuming python 2:

```
for key, value in aData.iteritems():
```

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
for key in dictionary.keys()
    value = dictionary[key]
    #do something
```

OR:

```
for key,value in dictionary.items():
    #do something
```